# automate transaction logshipping process for SQL server through Python script

Tags: python, sql-server

Want a way to automate the transaction logshipping process for SQL server through Python script. Also the secondary DB should get created in "stand-by" mode once we do the log shipping configuration.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: But why do you choose to ignore the built-in and **supported** [log shipping functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).